# Routing if using admin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have my application with 3 different access levels.

I want the admin to have access to all pages. For this to happen I put my code like this in the admin:

```
else if (claims.admin) { 
 return next() 
}
```

And this way the admin has access to all pages of the application.

But there is a problem, is that this way I log in with the admin and the admin stays the same on the login page and does not forward to any page. 
I want the admin to keep access to all the pages, but when logging in he will redirect him to the admin.vue page.

Full code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {    
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
if (userAuth) {
  firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
    .then(function ({
      claims
    }) {

if (claims.customer) {
  if (to.path !== '/customer')
   return next({
    path: '/customer',
   })
  } else if (claims.admin) {
  if (to.path !== '/admin')
   return next({
    path: '/admin',
   })
  } else if (claims.driver) {
if (to.path !== '/driver')
  return next({
   path: '/driver',
  })
 }     
 })
 })
```

Comment: You should take a piece of paper and draw a table with 3 columns: (a) the claims of the current customer, (b) the current page/route, (c) the page he is (or should be) going to. Then you will fill this table with all possible combinations and for each combination you will have to define the reaction - what the `beforeEach` will do in the given situation. When you have all combinations in front of you - it will be easy to define the behavior of the function.

Comment: @ IVO GELOV 
I still haven't been able to solve the problem. I'm using firebase, and I'm still unable to redirect to the admin page, keeping access to the other pages in the project. Can you put an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: homePage
    },
    {
      path: '/admin',
      component: adminPage,
      meta:
      {
        requiresAdmin: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/customer',
      component: customerPage,
      meta:
      {
        customerOnly: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/driver',
      component: driverPage,
      meta:
      {
        driverOnly: true
      }
    },
  ];
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>
{
  const role = getCurrentUserRole(); // somehow obtain the role of the current user - or NULL if the user is not logged in
  const requiresAdmin = to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAdmin);
  const customerOnly = to.matched.some(route => route.meta.customerOnly);
  const driverOnly = to.matched.some(route => route.meta.driverOnly);

  if(!role && (requiresAdmin || customerOnly || driverOnly)) next({name: 'loginPage'});
  else
  {
    if(requiresAdmin)
    {
      if(role == 'admin') next();
      else next({name: 'accessDenied'});
    }
    else if(customerOnly)
    {
      if(['admin', 'customer'].includes(role)) next();
      else next({name: 'accessDenied'});
    }
    else if(driverOnly)
    {
      if(['admin', 'driver'].includes(role)) next();
      else next({name: 'accessDenied'});
    }
    else next(); // this is public page
  }
});

export default router;
```

and in your `Login.vue`

```js
// Use whatever authorization system you need
firebase.login().then(user =>
{
  let routeName = 'Dashboard';
  switch(user.role)
  {
    case 'admin':
      routeName = 'AdminHome';
      break;
    case 'drvier':
      routeName = 'DriverHome';
      break;
    case 'customer':
      routeName = 'CustomerHome';
      break;
  }
  this.$router.push({name: routeName});
});
```